# Replace the first space in a column with a delimiting character

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that includes a bunch of text in one cell.  The first part of the text is a product# but the length varies.  The product number is separated from the other information by a space.

I'm looking to write a macro that will replace just the first space with a delimiting character. I usually use "~". This will then allow me to script a text-to-columns command that will isolate the product number in one column.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. Make an attempt. Post your results if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a formula:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(" ", A1, 1)-1) & "~" & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - FIND(" ", A1, 1))
```

Copy that down. Copy/PasteSpecial Values. Then text-to-column that result

Answer (score 1):

With VBA, the following approach is possible:

- Locate the first empty string position and write it to a variable
- Take the left part of the string to the position and append the replacement string
- Take the right part of the string from the position to the end and append the rest

This is the function:

```
Public Function ReplaceFirstSpace(myInput As String, _
                Optional replacement As String = "~") As String

    Dim position As Long
    position = InStr(1, myInput, " ")

    If position = 0 Then
        ReplaceFirstSpace = myInput
    Else
        ReplaceFirstSpace = Left(myInput, position - 1) & _
                            replacement & Right(myInput, Len(myInput) - position)

    End If

End Function
```

And some tests:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Debug.Print ReplaceFirstSpace("my name is")
    Debug.Print ReplaceFirstSpace("slim shaddy")
    Debug.Print ReplaceFirstSpace("tikitiki")
    Debug.Print ReplaceFirstSpace(" taram")
    Debug.Print ReplaceFirstSpace("tam ")
    Debug.Print ReplaceFirstSpace("")    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use REPLACE:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND(" ",A1),1,"~")
```